# Sending head of a linked list many times

Tags: c, linked-list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

is it possible to pass the head of an linked list two times like this? This works on codeblocks but not when its compiled in the terminal. I first pass the address of head to test() and then to append(). Am I completly lost or is this possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) {
  struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  struct Node* last = *head_ref;
  new_node->data = new_data;
  new_node->next = NULL;

  if (*head_ref == NULL) {
    *head_ref = new_node;
    return;
  }

  while (last->next != NULL) last = last->next;

  last->next = new_node;
  return;
}

void printList(struct Node* node) {
  while (node != NULL) {
    printf(" %d ", node->data);
    node = node->next;
  }
}

void test(struct Node* p) { append(p, 6); }

int main() {
  struct Node* head = NULL;

  test(&head);
  // append(&head, 6);
  printList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I imagine this code is producing a number of warnings and errors when complied. For example, your argument to `test()` is of an incorrect type.

Comment: Also, please describe how it "doesn't work". Does it cause your computer to catch on fire?

Comment: Close to a typo: `test` should be declared as `void test(struct Node** p) { append(p, 6); }`, because it get and pass a `Node **` and not a `Node *`. Indirections levels matter...

Answer (score 0):

correct from

```c
void test(struct Node* p) { append(p, 6); }
```

to

```c
void test(struct Node** p) { append(p, 6); }
```

and always compile with the following flags:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wpedantic
```

You would have found very quickly yourself the typo, hence the importance to use these flags:

```
head.c: In function ‘test’:
head.c:33:36: error: passing argument 1 of ‘append’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 void test(struct Node* p) { append(p, 6); }
                                    ^
head.c:9:6: note: expected ‘struct Node **’ but argument is of type ‘struct Node *’
 void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) {
      ^~~~~~
head.c: In function ‘main’:
head.c:38:8: error: passing argument 1 of ‘test’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   test(&head);
        ^
head.c:33:6: note: expected ‘struct Node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Node **’
 void test(struct Node* p) { append(p, 6); }
      ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to pass the head of an linked list two times like this?

It is possible and reasonable for a function to pass its parameter values on to other functions it calls, subject to type matching and conversion semantics.  All C parameters are passed by value, and the significance of a value is not derived from its source.

But no, you cannot do it *like that*, because the argument you are passing to `test()` does not have the correct type (`struct Node **` instead of `struct Node *`) and there is no standard automatic conversion from one to the other.  Undefined behavior results.  In practice, you might find that the compiler accepts the program and the program nevertheless behaves as you want, but it is not safe to rely on that.  It is reasonable to hope that the compiler will emit at least a warning about the type mismatch, and if it doesn't then you should look into options for making it emit more warnings.

On the other hand, if you corrected the type of `test()`'s parameter to match the call then calling `test(&head)` would be made equivalent to calling `append(&head, 6)` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the function `test` has the type `struct Node *`

```
void test(struct Node* p) { append(p, 6); }
```

while you are calling it passing an expression of the type `struct Node **`.

```
test(&head);
```

The compiler shall issue an error that there are used pointers of incompatible types.

So change the function declaration like

```
void test(struct Node** p) { append(p, 6); }
```

Pay attention to that the function `append` has a defect. It does not report whether a memory for new node was allocated successfully.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
int append( struct Node **head_ref, int new_data ) 
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = new_data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head_ref != NULL ) head_ref = &( *head_ref )->next;

        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
  
    return success;
}
```

As a result the function `test` can be declared an defined the following way

```
int test( struct Node **head_ref ) { return append( head_ref, 6); }
```

The function `printList` does not change the list. So its parameter should have the qualifier `const`.

```
void printList( const struct Node *node ) 
{
    for ( ; node != NULL; node = node->next ) 
    {
        printf( " %d ", node->data );
    }
}
```